# Cascading <select> not working with $event

Tags: angular, dropdown

Working with Angular 8 I'm having an issue understanding properly how my cascading dropdown doesn't work, here's the issue:

I have one select named **Pricelist** and another named **Currency**, Currency depend on Pricelist so the values are not shown before, ( values which I receive from a JSON ), the problem come from the fact that I don't know how to properly set the **[ngValue]** of Pricelist to render the currencie codes depending on the selected Pricelist.

Here's the code sample, thank you for your time

**HTML**

```
 <div class="flex2 pl10">
  <select formControlName="pricelist" class="form-control" (change)="selectedPriceListIndex = $event.target.value" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.pricelist.errors}" >
    <option value="" > Select a pricelist </option>
    <option  *ngFor="let p of filter.ListPricelist; let i = index;" [ngValue] ="p.id" id="pricelist_id" >{{p.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <div class="flex2 pl10">
  <select formControlName="currency" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.currency.errors}" class="form-control">
    <option value >Select a currency</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let c of filter.ListPricelist[selectedPriceListIndex]?.currencies" [ngValue]="c.id">{{c.code}}</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

**JSON**

[image]

**TS**

```
selectedPriceListIndex: number;
```

Comment: Give a try by changing `selectedIndex` instead of `value`

Comment: @Rajesh Nevermind, it's working but **Select a Pricelist** has the value of the first label